# Organizing groups of files and directories for deployment

Tags: deployment, version-control, organization

Our system consists of perhaps 30-40 different applications which require scripts and resources to run. These resources occur throughout the file system. We are often only deploying one application at a time. Some of the resources are shared and because we are deploying from a development system we often don't just want to just push everything each time .

Does anyone have tips or is there a tool that would help with creating organized groups of files for each application for deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout configuration management solutions like [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) and [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/).